# symfony symfony3 new single ManyToOne object ( owning side of the association )

Tags: symfony, model-associations

I have Cases, which also have Attachments. This is coded as a Case entity with the OneToMany association to Attachment entity. The Attachment entity has a ManyToOne association to Case entity. The code:

```
class Case {
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="case",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $attachments;

class Attachment
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Case", inversedBy="attachments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="case_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $case;
}
```

Im trying the following. I pretend to show/open the whole case into a single page. Inside the page, there will be the attachment list. At the end of that list, I pretend to put a form for new attachment submissions.

So I have written a controller to show the case, and I have created a new attachment form (AttachmentType ) and place it in the middle of the twig template, passing it into the render call of the action as a argument.

```
// CaseController.php
/**
 * @Route("/cases/show/{case}", name="showCase", requirements={ "case" : "\d+" } )
 */
public function showCaseAction(Request $request, $case)
{
    $theCase = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Case')->findOneById( $case );

    $attachment = new Attachment();
    $attachment->setCase( $theCase );
    $attachmentForm = $this->createForm(AttachmentType::class, $attachment);

    if ( ! $theCase ) {

        $this->addFlash('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('cases.show.case_not_found', [ '%case%' => $case ] ) );
    }

   return $this->render('cases/caseContainer.html.twig', array( 'case' => $theCase, 'attachmentform' => $attachmentForm->createView() ) );
}
```

And also I have written a newAttachmentAction into the controller to perform the attachment creation.

I stop writting my code here. I dont want to condition the possible answers.

My problem is that im not able to figure out how to recover the Case object when the newAttachmentAction is called, so I can do the association. I cant figure out if i should place something ( HiddenType,EntityType,etc ) into the Attachment Form Builder to store the Case object, or maybe would be better to use some other Symfony mechanism (Services, Closure, StorageTokens). I have made a wide search along the web, but i have read some many articles, that Im stucked ! Im probably missing the right search keywords.

I hope i have made my self clear, and therefore someone can point me into the right direction to find an example or a tutorial.

Best regards and many many thanks for your time and attention !

Comment: Hello, again
I've been keeping searching. I found something it helps to achieve the goal: DataTransformers. But Im not confortable with this solution. To include a hidden field into the form containing the ID value for the Case object , so I can retrieve the Case object when receiving back the form, works BUT HTML form fields values can be altered, easily, by modern browsers debug tools. 
I was thinking about a kind of server side association between, lets say, CSFR token and the Case object. 
Any suggestions into this way ?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a Case, i will add a HiddenType for attachment property inside the CaseformType.

Set data_class to Attachment

When you will create the form, you will pass a new instance of Case with the attachment reference.

After the post, when you will receive the form data, you will have the linked object

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your indication.
I dont want to create a case. I want to add attachments to an existing case, without using an editing case form.
I have modified my AttachmentFormType class and I have added a HiddenType with data_class set to the Case class object. 
In the controller I have set the Case in newAttachment action ( as it was ). Viewing the HTML you see the hidden form field set to case id. Good so far !
When I upload a new attachment, handleRequest says that a "Case object was expected, but a string was provided".
To be continued into the next comment ...

Comment: Im afraid that the HiddenType class doesnt convert the ID into a Case object by itself. Thats why I had to include a DataTransformer as its recomended **[here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)**.
One curiosity: taking a look at the **[documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html)** I have noticed that 'data_class' is not inherited by HiddenType class. But the parent class for HiddenType is FormType, which does have 'data_class' option.
Best regards @jeremy

Comment: And how about something like this?
$builder->add('attachment', 'hidden_entity', [
    'class' => Attachment::class
])